# How do I cite an entire published journal when discussing the journal itself?

Tags: citations, journals, publishers

One of the intended purposes of a citation is to help the reader locate and retrieve the information you are referring to whether they intend to substantiate it or to seek more detailed information. When you are discussing the purpose, intended audience, history, etc of an entire journal in part of your paper how would you cite the entire journal?

Answer (score 1):

> purpose, intended audience

Cite the journal's Aims & Scope page.

> history

Not sure what you're trying to cite out of the history, but cite whatever gave you the information you are citing. E.g. if you write "the journal published 30 papers in its inaugural issue", then cite the inaugural issue. If instead the sentence is "in 1999 the journal changed editor-in-chief", cite the news article.